# Errors adding a load balancer to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm pretty new to AWS and networking in general, but I am trying to serve a dotnet project using elastic beanstalk. I was able to get it running successfully, the health checks were good, and everything was smooth. It was running a single instance with a route 53 domain name, so going to the domain in http gives me a good response.

[image]

This is great, and I even verified that it was able to call one of our other apis over http. I wanted to add an SSL certificate so I could serve on https, and doing some research, I found that I need a load balancer in order to serve this. So, I changed it from a single instance to load balanced.

[image]

I then made sure that it served on https with my certificate, as well as http and gave it a default process that uses my healthcheck as its path

[image]

I then updated my route53 to point to the elastic beanstalk environment, and successfully accessed my website through http and https.

However, even though my instance was running, my elastic beanstalk environment health switched to "unknown" and said no data was received from the instance. I tried to change one of the environment variables I was running (because we could make calls on https now) and the update failed and reverted back. I tried this multiple times and it was always the same result.

[image]

Did I miss a step in adding a load balancer? Am I just not understanding something fundamental about AWS? What could be going on here, and what should I check?

I have verified that the load balancer is active, and that the target group is healthy. I have also verified that the security groups associated allow inbound and outbound traffic on 443 and 80. It isn't able to access any of the external APIs we had earlier, but that could be because it is still trying to do them with the old endpoints over http.

Comment: Try to switch to load balancer without setting listeners and https stuffs.  You should first figure out whether the problem comes from load balancer or https.  If you can find anything from your logs inside /var/logs that can be helpful.